# ActiveJDBC MAX() function

Tags: activejdbc

I'm new to ActiveJDBC and Java.
How can I do

```
SELECT MAX(age) FROM persons
```

with ActiveJDBC on a MySQL database?

I have tried

```
Pesrsons.find("MAX(age)")
```

but this one returns an empty list
and

```
Persons.FindBySql("SELECT MAX(age) FROM persons")
```

this other one returns null.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use .find() to execute a custom "SELECT" query.

But with .findBySql() this should work `Persons.FindBySql("SELECT MAX(age) as age FROM persons")`